# How can I check if username already exists in the file

Tags: c#, file, filter, filtering

In a class, I am entering data to create an account. Now every data that is entered by the user is saved in a file. Now for the Username, I want to check if the username already exists the file. How can I do this?

```
      public void CreateAccount()
      {

        Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Username: ");

        Client usernameField = new Client("Username")
        {
            UsernameField = Console.ReadLine()
        };


        string filePath = "C:\\createaccount.txt"

        Client.SerializeData(accountData, filePath);

    public static void SerializeData(List<Client> userToSerialize, string 
    filePath)
    {
        FileReadWrite<Client>.SerializeData(userToSerialize, filePath);
    }

    public static List<Client> DeserializeData<Client>(string filePath)
    {
        return FileReadWrite<Client>.DeserializeData<Client>(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: 1. `DeserializeData` the data, 2.check if the `List<Client>` contains `UsernameField` that was entered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deserialize the existing data stored in the file.

```
var listOfClients = Client.DeserilizeData(fileName);
```

This would give you a list of existing users. Then you can use Linq to check if Username already exists

```
var exists = listOfclients.Any(x=>x.UsernameField.Equals(newUserName));
```

If the user name is case-insensitive, you need to use

```
var exists = listOfclients.Any(x=>x.UsernameField.Equals(newUserName,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

**Update based on your code.**

```
Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
Console.WriteLine("Enter a Username: ");

Client usernameField = new Client("Username")
{
    UsernameField = Console.ReadLine()
};
var listOfClients = Client.DeserilizeData(fileName);
var exists = listOfclients.Any(x=>x.UsernameField.Equals(usernameField.UsernameField ));
```

Comment: The newUserName where it is implemented?

Comment: newUserName would be the value  given by the user, var newUsername = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: I don't know why the value that is inputted by the user is always null :(

Comment: Updated the answer based on your code, could you check now

Comment: 'var myRetrievedClients = Client.DeserializeData<Client>(filePath);

 

bool exists = myRetrievedClients.Any(x => x.UsernameField.Equals(UsernameField));'

Comment: Would be interesting to know how your read User input in your new code ? Also i have updated the answer to match your code flow. Could you please check that as well ?

Comment: @AndréColeiro that's not exactly i wanted to see. You mentioned that you always ended up with value given by the User as null. So, i wanted to see how you read using Console.ReadLine() and assign that variable, later, using it as described in the code above.

Comment: in the above code in your comment, is nameUser, surnameUser etc instances of Client ? In the OP, I believe you are asking getting the User Input via Console.ReadLine. You then wanted to check if this given user name is already in the serialized file . This looks out of context ? or am reading it wrong ?

Comment: I read the user input from the usernameField not from UsernameField = Console.ReadLine()

Comment: usernameField is the Property of Client Class to which you are assinging the username field. In the first part of code sample you have shared in OP, you are asking User to Input username, and then reading them to Client.usernameField. If you check the second part of my answer, "Updated code", I have used the instance of Client you have created to check if it exists in the serialized data.

Comment: So basically what you are doing is, asking the user to enter a username, store in usernameField property of an instance of Client, then you deserialize currently stored Client instances from the File, check if newly entered username exists in any of the instances in the serialized file.

Comment: Okay m8, I'll try it when I arrive at home and thanks for your patience.

Comment: @AndréColeiro Glad to help, kindly mark it as answer if helps you resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks, It has worked :). Sorry for the late response

Comment: @AndréColeiro Glad to help